# Official way to get RTSP URL of a youtube video

Tags: youtube-api

I understand that youtube provide player API's for android/IOS and web. However I would like to play youtube videos with in my application which is written in C++ using gstreamer. In order to stream a video I need to have a RTSP url for the video. However I could not find any official documentation on that in you tube developer documentation. Is this something that is officially supported by youtube?

Comment: This is not supported by YouTube and would break their terms of service.

Comment: Thanks. Do they provide a java player that can be embedded in a normal Java application? I know they provide an android player, by my application is not an android app.

Comment: Have you looked at the Java samples here? https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/tree/master/java

Comment: I will take a look. But just now I realized that, even if there is a player that works with standard JAVA, it will not work in this scenario as I need to use a specific hardware accelerated decoder for decoding. I am wondering how this work in XBMC?